# SCP exit 0 when using un-initialized variable and fail to copy

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, scp, variables

I am trying to test if a file fails to transfer using SCP.

I noticed if I use a **un-initialized variable**, I get exit 0 even though the SCP fails.

For example, I have an empty variable called **uninitialized_var**

```
[root@centos_8_0 scripts]# echo $uninitialized_var
```

If I try to use it in SCP command, the command appears to work, returns exit 0, however no file is copied due to non-existent path.  If I use a hard path that does not exist, it will fail.

```
[root@centos_8_0 scripts]# scp root@centos_8_1:/root/test/stack_test/file_20210302.csv $uninitialized_var/file_20210302.csv
file_20210302.csv                                                                                                                                                     100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

```
[root@centos_8_0 scripts]# echo $?
0
```

Is there a way to test if copy succeeded?  Currently I am using:

```
  
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then... 
however like I said it returns 0.
```

Is there a reason why it returns 0?

Answer (score 2):

The variable will be expanded by the shell and in this case prepended to `/file_20210302.csv`. This means that your destination path is just `/file_20210302.csv`. You are performing this action as root which has write permission to `/`. The files are being copied and placed in your root directory, no error is occurring so the exit status is 0.

I tested this with

```
scp user@example.com:/home/user/test_file  $uninitialized_var/tmp/test_file
```

and it worked as expected, placed the file in /tmp and exit status 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using bash, you can supply a default value for the variable, to be used if the variable is not set.

```
echo ${uninitialized_var:-NOT_SET}/file_20210302.csv
```

If the variable is not set, it will "return" the value "NOT_SET" instead.
You can also supply a more sensible default value, e.g.

```
scp root@centos_8_1:/tmp/file_20210302.csv ${uninitialized_var:-/tmp}/file_20210302.csv
```

If uninitialized_var is set, scp will write to that folder.
If not, it will write the file to /tmp.

Refer to [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: Thanks for the solution.   Explained perfectly.